# Unable to connect to my mail Server (java)

Tags: java, email

```
public class ConnectGmail {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {


    PasswordAuthentication authentication;

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    Store store = session.getStore("imap");

    try {

      store.connect(host , user , "password");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Got this ERROR .. I almost tried with all the protocol

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection refused: connect;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:571)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
    at ConnectGmail.main(ConnectGmail.java:26)
```

any help ??

Comment: `HOST` or `host`? `USR` or `user`? `PASSWORD` or the `authentication` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the mail authentification before you can use it:

Set property `mail.smtp.auth` to `true` to enalbe authentification.

> If true, attempt to authenticate the user using the AUTH command. Defaults to false.

@see Javadoc of Package com.sun.mail.smtp

Comment: Why `mail.smtp.auth` property for `imap` ?

Answer (score 0):

Does your ISP allow you to connect to that port?

Do you have to go through a proxy?

Try opening a direct connection to the mail server with the right port using a simple `telnet <host> <port>` command. If you can't then it's not your connection that fails, it's your ISP that disallows it. If you can, check if you use specific proxy options and add them in your program.

Comment: server name suggests he's on a corporate network of some sort. 
to me it looks more like he's not authorised to access the mailserver.