# Connect to mail server using MAPI

Tags: java, email, mapi

I would like to connect to my enterprise mail server ..But i can only usi MAPI protocol it seems . how can i establish a connection to my Enterprise mail server using Java MAPI API

Comment: Both of your questions seem similar to me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230252/unable-to-connect-to-my-mail-server-java

Comment: but there i am trying to connect using imap. But i just got to know that i can not use IMAP So i want to use MAPI instead of IMAP . So it's a different question ..

Comment: I'm seeing that people are lazy to Google for solutions these days. They think SO is a magic sphere where all knowledge is found.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the short answer is: you can't.  MAPI is incompatible with managed languages (.Net, Java, etc.) because the garbage collection plays havoc with internal memory management.  Your only option is to spawn an external process using an unmanaged language (e.g. C++, VB6) and using cross-process calls for any MAPI functions.  You can do this using, for example, a COM EXE.  This has the disadvantage that cross-process calls have a lot of overhead and, as a result, tend to be slow; but it may be your only option.